# Passing environment-dependent variables in nativescript & angular2

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am building a mobile app using NativeScript (2.3.0) and Angular2 (2.0.0)

I am struggling how to keep environment variables out of our source code in the way that they are loaded depending the environment (dev / test / prod).

Ideally I would like to have dedicated files that holds them (.env.dev
.env.test .env.prod) but I am open to any solution that works.

I could not find any help neither Native Script docs nor googling.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I got a solution and I post it for future references:

inspired on this docs: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-pass-environment-variables%3F

It is all about publishing variables in the global namespace and using Webpack to override them through `new webpack.DefinePlugin` (https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dependency-injection).

Step by step guide:

- install Webpack as NS module: `tns install webpack` (more info https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/bundling-with-webpack)
- install Webpack as node_module: `npm install --save-dev webpack` (I know it seems redundant but it is the only way I found to have access to webpack object from webpack.config.js)
- Modify in the webpack.config.js in the following way: (other configuration not relevant has been omitted)

  ```
  var bundler = require("nativescript-dev-webpack");
  var webpack = require("webpack");

  module.exports = bundler.getConfig({

    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify('dev'),
        'API_URL': JSON.stringify('my_api_url'),
        'HMR': 'whatever',
      })
    ]
  });
  ```

In `/app` folder create the following file aiming to populate the global namespace with global variables (as said they will be overridden by Webpack)

`global-environment.ts`

```
// Extra variables that live on Global that will be replaced by webpack DefinePlugin
declare var ENV: string;
declare var HMR: boolean;
declare var API_URL: string;

interface GlobalEnvironment {
    ENV;
    HMR;
    API_URL;
}
```

Done!

Maybe you have a better way / improvements on this. I am glad to hear them.